# Why my question is hold on?

Tags: support, scope, closed-questions

I asked at:

[Sum of energy from torques of several disks in double rotation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143087/sum-of-energy-from-torques-of-several-disks-in-double-rotation)

It is on hold, but I don't find another forum or question where this problem is resolved. It's possible to use lower number of disks, 16 at least, but I can't think with 2 or 3 disks.

Answer (score 2):

The closing notice tells you *exactly* why your question is on hold, and links to [our homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) - what more do you want to know? Please also have a look at [our stance on check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583).

That you cannot find the solution to your problem elsewhere is unfortunate, but that does not mean that we have to solve it for you (or check your solution).

Comment: That FAQ topic says the OP needs to "... show your work. Explain what you've been able to figure out so far and how you did it." In this case, didn't the OP do that, in the paragraph of the closed question which begins "I compute work from torques"? So which part of the homework FAQ is this question not in compliance with, what change would they need to make to the question to make it re-openable?

Comment: @ChrisW: There's no *conceptual question*. The closing notice says: *"Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem."* There's an *and*, not an *or*, which means that no matter how much work OP shows us, unless they ask about something more conceptual than "Is this right?" or "How to proceed from here?" the question remains off-topic.

Comment: Ah yes I found your [argument against "check-my-work questions" here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6097/3773) -- the question is off-topic because the question is, "can you help me find my error?"

Comment: So it's just my question ? I asked this but in fact I don't know if the method is good or not, or maybe there is a problem with first thermodynamic law.

Comment: @Sx7 Maybe [this answer](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6233/3773) is good at explaining what's on-topic: you would need to ask a question about the physics, not about its mathematical representation.