# Is it permissible to re-post another member’s unanswered question?

Tags: discussion

[This question was asked nearly 24 h ago](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203089/how-to-solve-the-following-question-about-quantum-mechanical-wave-function) and didn’t receive an answer so far.

It was downvoted 6 times, presumably because:

1. It’s homework and the OP didn’t show any effort at working out an answer.
2. The question was poorly formatted (mostly a screenshot of an exam/homework site).

OP was also unresponsive to comments made.

The question is now on hold.

I’ve tried working out the problem but haven’t come up with anything worthy of an answer. But I’m very interested to see if this problem has a solution and if so which is it? For that reason I’d like to post the question again, as my own, properly formatted and with partial workings out because I believe posted that it that way, may attract those who may know how to answer it.

*But I’m afraid the new question would be flagged as a duplicate.*

One other possibility is to heavily edit the existing question but there’s the risk that this will be interpreted as not in the spirit of the OP’s question.

Yet another possibility is to allow more time, hoping someone will provide an answer but considering the *6 down votes and the hold status* that seems unlikely.

Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Be aware that just showing work ***does not*** render homework-like question acceptable. Please read [the meta question that is linked when questions are closed as homework-like](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/).

Comment: Also: *This is what we have bounties for*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Points 1 and 2 are precisely why I downvoted the post in question (which will likely be auto-deleted soon, so I've saved the screenshot and linked [it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8onD.png)); I suspect that the same reasons are why it was closed as well (though more for 1 than 2).

Posting the *same* question would mean that you are running afoul of the [**homework policy**](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) *and* duplicating the question; both would get your question closed (I'd lean more towards the HW reason if I saw it).

And as much as people say it in comments, adding your effort doesn't actually prevent your homework question from being closed as homework. Note that the **tl;dr** on the HW policy says,

> It's not enough to just show your work and ask where you went wrong. If you just need someone to check your work, you can always seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Which is quite in line with the community's opinion on [**check my work**](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) questions.

All of that said, you *can* repost the question yourself **if** you make it about the *particular physical concept*, and not "How is this question solved?" that it currently is posed as. This will probably take some thinking on your part on how to phrase it such that it doesn't violate the site policies, but I imagine it can be done.

Comment: yes, it is possible to rethink the question in function of a specific physical concept, so I'll probably do that. I have a screenshot of it myself. Thank you.