# How to automate "not a homework help site" comment?

Tags: support, homework-and-exercises

While reviewing I often have to make this comment:

> Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Is there an automated way to write this comment?

Do I have to keep its copy somewhere else and copy-paste it every time?

Or there is some shortcut?

Comment: I can't remember who originally wrote that comment, but I keep a copy as a text file and copy and paste it when I need it.

Comment: Or make up you very own personalised message :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie I copied yours. :-) ;-)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform That's very long piece of writing!!!!

Answer (score 3):

There is no in-built mechanism for automated comment insertion. Many people who leave similar messages often either re-type them by hand every time, or have a text file or other location from which they copy-paste.

On the other hand, there are several third-party scripts at [stack**apps**](https://stackapps.com/) which modify the SE sites' functionality to add this sort of feature, such as e.g.

- [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se),

which enables you to write your own pre-written comments using a quick button:

[image]

(Note that I've never used this script, but it looks straightforward enough.)

Comment: I have never used stack apps. Its confusing for me. Can you suggest me a good app directly through link?

Comment: @AnubhavGoel That is precisely what I already linked to. Frankly, if you want me to provide any assistance you need to show evidence that you've done your due diligence in pursuing the avenues I suggested.

Comment: I clicked on Google chrome extension link there. I got some page of reminder. Does it mean , it works like this on Google chrome and Firefox?

Comment: @AnubhavGoel Apologies if this wasn't clear enough: **I do not provide support for that StackApps application**. If you have questions, the StackApps page itself is the place to go. (In addition to that, a question such as the one you phrased, with information below the minimal level about your environment, are unlikely to be answerable by anyone at all. So do your due diligence first.)

Comment: You can also try posting a question here and asking for help (which may or may not get closed depending on how on-topic people feel it is, since there already is a support forum for that app). But, as I said, you have provided essentially **none** of the information that would be needed to help you. What browser are you using, what link did you click, and what "page of reminder" did it show you? Without that information, it is impossible to help, and not displaying it shows a disregard for the people you're hoping will help you. Don't complain at me for your failure to ask correctly.