# About the formula wants (Let everyone read this)

Tags: support, homework-and-exercises, specific-question, close-reasons

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: [Kepler's Third Law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362667/)

Why did my question become off-topic? I just wanted to get a formula and said that I will solve it myself. Why aren't formula questions allowed? As far as i know, the formulas are in conceptual physics. Then, I'm asking a conceptual question. Please, do it at least because you don't admit a conceptual question too. What do you really admit?

**EDIT:** Giving formulas does not mean ''Solving for you'' If they don't know how to apply that equation or not have any idea about the question, they won't be able to solve question. It depends on what they know. But you all don't have any respect, everyone starts hitting that close button when they see that cool ''homework-exercises'' tag. Answer formula wants at least. We got your homework policies and it seems good. But this is really being funny. The site admits conceptual question and this was really conceptual. That's why everyone does not understand this site.

Please, decide what kind of questions you want. If you want a question like this ''What is that?, What is this?'' Everyone can google it so it doesn't matter. What is this site for then? Examined other stackexchange communities, they are very helpful for a student. If you were right, then why do they answer all kind of questions? everyone gets everything well.

Let's talk about physics.se now. Yes, homework-questions should not be allowed and you are too right. But if you don't admit the formula questions, then that's being too funny. Assume I posted my question here, and asked a formula to solve it myself. Did you solve it for me? No. Who did solve it? Me. What did you show? the true equation him ought to use. Did you give the final answer? No. Does him have any idea about question? If answer is no, then he won't be able to solve it =)

Let's talk about other stackexchange communities, They get both questions. Conceptual-Homework. I posted my questions which I really did not get and took great answers. By the way, I leant everything and saw my faults. They are respectful for students because they see that him does not have any idea about the question. You might be right at homework-questions but really not right at formula questions. Believe in me, by doing this, you are helping no one. If you were really right at this, other stackexchange communties may have been following your policies.

I lost my family from a traffic accident and do not have money to go courses and my physics teacher is too agressive as well. By the way, Trying to post my questions here and that's being off-topic without any reason. I asked them a formula, not final answer or something. Trying to learn something from these communities. Please, be respectful. I hope you change I lost my family from a traffic accident and do not have money to go courses and my physics teacher is too agressive as well. By the way, Trying to post my questions here and that's being off-topic without any reason. I asked them a formula, not final answer or something. Trying to learn something from these communities. Please, be respectful. I'm not telling you to answer homework-questions. If you admit the conceptual questions, then you should answer the formula wants. Like i said, him ought to just ask an equation for question. If he wants the final answer or did not show his idea, then it should be off-topic. It seems like this will be off-topic cause telling true things. I hope you all change your unnecessilary policies. As the last thing I'll say, do not help him with calcuation cause the formula will be enough.

Let me give an example;

[Acceleration of center of disc](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362682/acceleration-of-center-of-disc)

You did well for this question.

[Kepler's Third Law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362667/keplers-third-law)

But look at this question and see what's different between.

**(1)** The first one wanted you to calcuate and give final answer for him.

**(2)** The second one wanted you to show a formula not give final answer for him and had said that he will solve it hisself. What's wrong then?

Take my mind as an idea, discuss about this.

Comment: There are plenty of free learning resources for physics that provide formulae.  Even if you can't afford anything, as long as you can manage to get Internet access, the information can be found.  We don't really want people coming here every time they don't know a formula; that information exists in many other places.

Comment: @JMac It is not okay to kick everyone to other forums. What is this site for? It is too easy to google it and it does not take your time to show a thing or help someone. I'm not supporting the homework-questions. I'm telling that the formula questions never been homework-questions. Do not help him in calcuation. just show what him needs and he will think about that and try to solve it. If him knows what to do, already solved that question then. Take my mind as an idea and discuss about this.

Comment: @JMac Homework policy seems good, did not say a thing about that. I mean the formula questions. You will see that the formula questions are in conceptual physics and never been anything other. It's too normal. Do not help anyone with calcuation. Just show him the true equation to use.

Comment: Believe in me, It won't take your time to show an equation. Now this site will have an aim and you will see that him solved the problem with your equation. If him wants more like calcuation/near to final answer, then it ought to be off-topic.

Comment: No one is "kicking" anyone to anywhere.  I think AccidentalFourierTransform's answer provides some good insight as to why we don't see providing formulae as a beneficial practice.  It is not actually a conceptual question to ask "What formula do I use here?"  Formulae are not concepts, they are the application of concepts.  You can ask _conceptual_ questions about formulae; but asking if a formula is appropriate is not a conceptual question in itself, it is a question about the exercise.  It _does_ take time to provide or verify an equation for someone.

Comment: @JMac What does ''There's other forums'' mean? I had saw too many comments like that.

Comment: But more importantly; people here are volunteers.  Many of the volunteers (and especially those who participate in the meta and have been vocal about policies) have agreed that such questions are not in line with the site we wish to be.  If we start allowing such questions, the site would become flooded with them.  Our members have decided that they do not wish to deal with such questions.  I don't blame them.  It's not interesting for us to verify or provide formulae for students.  It is interesting to discuss underlying concepts; which are the types of questions that are well received.

Comment: @JMac You are absoulety too right at that. But If you read everything what I wrote, will get what i mean. Do not allow homework-questions and something like that. Just allow the formula questions. Do not help anyone in calcuation and near to answer. Just show him the true equation to solve it.

Comment: The page on [homework & exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) covers quite a bit of information (including those other forums that may help) if you're willing to look.  Also, perhaps the most relevant point that I forgot to bring up; we have another policy on [check-my-work](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) questions, which are off-topic.  Your question was a check my work question, looking for us to verify a formula.

Comment: @JMac I had read that policy and seems good. I want you to change your minds about the formula questions. It won't take your time to show an equation for him. If he knows everything about that question, then will solve it easily. Do not help him with calcuation and near to answer. Just show him the true equation him ought to follow. Then, you will see that he solved it.

Comment: @JMac Take my topic as an idea and discuss about this. If you run this idea, will see that this site has an aim. It's not hard to type ''What is momentum?'' on google. So, everyone is being like robot.

Comment: You still seem to be missing the point. "Just allowing formula questions" is essentially the exact same as allowing homework as far as member contribution is concerned.  You're essentially saying "Give me every piece of information I need to solve this problem without critically thinking.".  The reason I say that is because many of us were not always told the equation to use when doing physics.  The point is to research yourself in the textbooks and _understand_ why you are using those formulae.  Us telling you which equations to use doesn't help you in the long run.

Comment: @JMac It's not same with allowing ''homework-questions''. I just tell you that help him with equation. Do not deal with other things like calcuation or etc. He will try to solve it with your equation as your equation won't be near to answer. There's a different between ''homework-questions'' and ''Formula wants''. The first one wants you to solve it for him. Other one just wants to get help about the question and as will solve it himself

Comment: You're still ignoring my main point, and the point of AccidentalFourierTransform's post.  Getting the right equation in a situation is generally the hardest part of homework and exercises.  Anyone who has taken algebra can substitute values in for the variables and get the solution if given the formula.  You won't really _learn_ physics if you are always given the formula to use in each situation.  You'll just be doing algebra that gives physical results.  In my opinion, it's not "helping" anyone to spend our time checking other peoples work or providing them equations.

Comment: @JMac This seems to be an iteration of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362330/finding-the-true-equation-for-angular-velocity

Comment: @ZeroTheHero That's deleted, so I can't see it (maybe in another 20 days if [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361679/why-do-pens-write-better-on-pages-that-have-pages-below-them/) stays on Hot Network Questions :P)

Comment: @JMac Why aren't other communities getting spammed then? They allow all kind of questions and giving great answers. Just run it for a while you will see. We aren't on homework-questions. The trouble is at Formula wants. Read all what i wrote... You said: ''In my opinion, it's not "helping" anyone to spend our time checking other peoples work or providing them equations'' and hitting close button before read the question is not helping anyone as well. Recently days,  Floris said ''Let's read the question before hitting close button'' and only him answered my questions as nicely.

Comment: @Liam Other communities do get spam.  Other communities also are allowed to have different policies on homework.  Math SE for example, seems more prone to just solving any problem given to them.  Engineering SE has similar (though less fleshed out) homework policies to Physics.  There are times where a "help vampire" will fill up the new questions with homework questions; and it's really annoying.  Quite honestly, I would see no personal value in answering a question by just providing an equation.  Good questions make the _person answering_ think as well.

Comment: @JMac Other communities getting spammed but not too much. They have a great policy. I asked my math and chemistry questions, got nicely answers. I also prepared my exams with their answers and knew what to do in exam. You're still on homework-questions. Did I tell a thing about homework-questions? Homework policy seems good.

Comment: I also did read your question before hitting the close button.  Specifically, I noticed that you were looking to have your formula checked.  That's not a good question here, that's a yes or no question.  The answers are boring and take more work to check than to actually write.  If you have a reason to doubt about using a formula, then ask the conceptual question you have.  Don't post the formula and ask if it's right.  If you have no idea what formula to use; do some research on your own; then come back if there are any concepts holding you up.  Finding information for yourself is priceless.

Comment: @JMac They won't ask it's right or not. If he  doubts  it,  will ask here. Also I mean he will check his equation before posting his question here. If that's wrong, will research something about that. Then he will post it here.  If he wants to get help in calcuation or near to the final answer, that will be off-topic. However, If he wants to get a true equation to solve that question by showing his thinking, then it should be on-topic.

Comment: @JMac https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362684/parabolic-co-ordinate-system This really should be off-topic. He wants to get help in calcuation. Look at the difference between ''Formula wants'', ''Homework-questions''.

Comment: @JMac This poster had a similar “what equation should I use” question a couple of days ago, followed by a (apparently now deleted) meta post of the type you have here.  It would be more constructive for everyone if the poster worked on editing his/her questions to they fit the guidelines but to each his/her own.  There we go: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10209/is-this-really-first-time-ive-seen-this

Comment: @ZeroTheHero It was a good example to show what i mean. As far as I remember, he was asking what equation he needs use. Did he want an answer about calcuation? No. Did he want an answer near to final answer? No. Did he show his research? Yes. Did he show his equation? Yes. Then, what would the problem be? He knows the true equation, already will solve it easily. Just clutch what's different between ''Formula wants/help'' and ''Homework-questions''.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Look at my example: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362667/keplers-third-law then look at this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362679/speed-of-river-problem you will get what i mean and see what's different between ''Formula wants'' and ''Homework-questions''. If you run it, this site will have an aim. Discuss about this.

Comment: @Liam Based on the fact that there were multiple good responses from moderators and community members on that other, very similar question, I see no reason to keep having this circular discussion.  You want something from this site that the members have agreed is outside of the scope of the site.  If you want to change that policy; it will require a lot of community support.  To get that; I think you would need to come up with some better reasons than you have given here.  I wont stop you from making a meta discussion on that topic; but I wouldn't expect positive results.

Comment: @JMac My reasons and given examples are too great examples.

Comment: @Liam You've ignored me about 20 times when I said that "Check my work" is **off-topic** for this site.  Your question on Kelper's Law is _exactly_ that.  Also, the site has an aim as is; that is why we close questions that go against our agreed purpose.

Comment: @JMac That wasn't ''check my work''. You aren't getting what i mean. Everyone won't wait an answer like ''Yes, this is correct.'' He will research about his question and if he doubts it then he will ask it here.

Comment: @Liam You're asking for the "correct" formula.  To answer your question, they will either say "Yes, that equation works" or "No, use this equation".  You're either looking for us to check your work on that equation, or you're looking for us to do the work by finding it for you.  So it's either "check my work" or "homework and exercises".  None of what you ask is related to a concept; it is entirely related to getting a solution.

Comment: @JMac Look at my example: physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362667/keplers-third-law then look at this: physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362679/… you will get what i mean and see what's different between ''Formula wants'' and ''Homework-questions''

Comment: I'm done smashing my head against this brick wall.

Comment: @JMac If you look at mine, there's some faults. I did not show my question as an example. I just want you to get what's different between ''Formula wants'' and ''Homework-questions''.

Comment: @JMac that is an *impressive* show of patience and goodwill.

Comment: @Zero This meta thread https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10209/is-this-really-first-time-ive-seen-this is not deleted, it was just hidden from the front page of meta due to its low score. (The question on main it refers to, on the other hand, was deleted when the user account was removed.) Just for the record.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Yes I realized after having written my comment but thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 5):

"*formula questions*" could mean anything. If the question is "give me the formula to solve my problem", then the answer is *no*: such questions are disallowed. On the other hand, if your question is about the physics behind some concept, then the answer is *yes*: such questions are allowed. Unfortunately, your post is of the first kind.

Note that when it comes to undergraduate physics, knowing which is the right formula to use is usually the hardest part of the problem. Therefore, if someone gave you the formula you are asking for, they would essentially be solving your problem for you. Algebraic manipulations to a formula is usually straightforward, and does not represent a significant part of solving a problem. But *knowing which formula to use* does.

The policy of this community is: we will not solve your problems for you. We will do our best to help you understand the physics behind the problem, but we will not solve it for you. This is the official policy of this community.

I will not discuss whether I agree or not with this policy. But it is there, and until it is changed, we will have to live with it, like it or not. Try to change your question to comply with this policy, and it will be reopened. For now, it will most likely stay closed.

Note that people have been trying to modify this policy for years. Don't expect it to be changed because of you, and don't expect us to make an exception *just this time*. It won't happen and you would be wasting everybody's time. The best you can do is to edit your post into something that is on-topic. Asking for a formula is not, and will not be in the foreseeable future, on-topic.

If your concern about this policy goes beyond your particular post, you are welcome to discuss it in general terms, but do note that there are dozens of post here on meta about that. Please read them before making new suggestions. Get used to the idiosyncrasies of the community, and make sure you understand the context behind every decision that has been taken. It will lead to a much more mature and  fruitful discussion. Trying to change how an established community works just because you need something from it at a particular moment of your life is truly execrable and just as selfish as it gets. Trying to change it because you care about the well-being of the community is very commendable and we would all be very thankful for such an attitude.

Comment: You say that you admit the conceptual questions. I've already asked a conceptual question also did not mean ''Give me the formula to solve my problem'', ''I doubt this formula, Could you show anohter?''. Really, what you admit then? Is it really too hard to show an equation at least? Everyone might learn easily with that. Okay, you are right at homework troubles. But not right at formula questions. I had put that question to show what i mean.

Comment: Giving formulas does not mean ''Solving for you'' If they don't know how to apply that equation or not have any idea about the question,  they won't be able to solve question. It depends on what they know. But you all don't have any respect, everyone starts hitting that close button when they see that cool ''homework-exercises'' tag.  Answer formula wants at least. We got your homework policies and it seems good. But this is really being funny. The site admits conceptual question and this was really conceptual. That's why everyone does not understand this site.

Comment: Please, decide what kind of questions you want. If you want a question like this ''What is that?, What is this?'' Everyone can google it so it doesn't matter. What is this site for then? Examined other stackexchange communities, they are very helpful for a student. If you were right, then why do they answer all kind of questions? Everyone gets everything well.

Comment: Let's talk about physics.se now. Yes, homework-questions should not be allowed and you are too right. But if you don't admit the formula questions, then that's being too funny. Assume I posted my question here, and asked a formula to solve it myself. Did you solve it for me? No. Who did solve it? Me. What did you show? the true equation him ought to use. Did you give the final answer? No. Does him have any idea about question? If answer is no, then he won't be able to solve it =).

Comment: Let's talk about other stackexchange communities, They get both questions. Conceptual-Homework. I posted my questions which I really did not get and took great answers. By the way,  I leant everything and saw my faults. They are respectful for students because they see that him does not have any idea about the question. You might be right at homework-questions but really not right at formula questions. Believe in me, by doing this, you are helping no one. If you were really right at this, other stackexchange communties may have been following your policies.

Comment: I lost my family from a traffic accident and do not have money to go courses and my physics teacher is too agressive as well. By the way, Trying to post my questions here and that's being off-topic without any reason. I asked them a formula not final answer or something. Trying to learn something from these communities. Please, be respectful. This makes everyone sad. I'm posting all kind of  questions and getting nicely answers. I do not tell you to answer homework-questions, I'm telling you that you should answer conceptual questions like formula wants.