# Role of moderators in reviewing flags

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderators

[A question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/348145/question-about-the-operating-of-forces-in-a-physics-problem) I asked a while ago has been put on hold because the moderators think my question does not satisfy the criteria of a good homework question. I disagreed with that assertion so I [flagged](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/164413) my question. It was declined with this response:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of
>   content that requires their intervention

I may have made a mistake by writing in my flag statement that I wanted an explanation for marking my question as off-topic. I actually wanted them to either remove the off-topic remark from my question or give a clearer explanation about where I went wrong with my question.

But I am now unsure about the role of moderators in such cases. Did the moderators not put my question on hold? Are they not the ones who can intervene and mark my question as valid again?

Comment: If you're looking for a bit more reason why your question was closed as off topic, it appears to me to be a [check my work](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6097/127931) question.

Comment: @JMac The answer in the link states that a questioner should clearly  his thought processes and ask why his reasoning is wrong. I also have explained my thought process when solving this question.

Comment: @JMac Please let me know if you have any suggestions for improving my question.

Comment: It says the questioner should clearly show their thought process and ask a conceptual question.  "Does my reasoning make sense?" isn't conceptual.

Comment: @JMac The answer states: _There must be a reasonable explanation (by established physics, of course) of why the derivation is expected to work in the eye of the asker,...._ I believe I have done this. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: @JMac I never asked whether or not my reasoning made sense. I simply asked where my mistake was because given my knowledge and understanding of the subject, I could not see it.

Comment: There's no indication that you even think it's wrong.  You're just asking "does this look correct?"  You're not asking about any specific physics concept.  If you think there's a specific part of the problem where you're trying to clear up a concept, try to focus on that.

Comment: @JMac _There's no indication that you even think it's wrong._ Okay, I agree with this claim. I modified my question again to better explain my doubts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reviewing and (possibly) re-opening questions is part of the normal operation of the site—it is the purview of normal users with at least 3000 reputation. It does not call for the intervention of [elected moderators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) (distinguished by a ♦ after their username) who are there to deal with unusual or rapidly evolving cases.