# "Homework and check-my-work" close reason confusion

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons

So recently I get my [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/550446/prove-that-l-t-v-is-a-proper-lagrangian) closed. While it is entirely up to the community to decide whether a question is on topic or not, I got really confused by the feedback:

> [Homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) are considered off-topic here, particularly when asking about specific computations instead of underlying physics concepts.

I followed the two links and here is what I found for the definition of homework-like questions:

> A "homework question" is any question whose value lies in helping you understand the method by which the question can be solved, rather than getting the answer itself.

Yet I failed to see why my question is a homework like question, as otherwise the underlying method would be a general solution of a generic type of question, with my question be a specific case. However I don't think the underlying method can be generalized, as $L=T-V$ is already a generic case, and trying to generalize the method to prove that $L=4T-\sqrt{3}V$ is proper is just pure nonsense.

Also I don't think the question is remotely similar to a check-my-work question, and I got quite confused for my question to be closed for this reason. I have thought that maybe it would be closed for being to broad, or as a duplicate, yet homework close reason was a surprise for me.

**My question** So would anyone explain why my question is homework-like or check-my-work, and how can I improve it and avoid making future mistakes?

Comment: Note: the question got three "homework-like" close votes, and two "duplicate" close votes.

Comment: @rob Note: I've been on this site for years and contributed many answers, and I find the homework close reason not only confusing but blatantly self-contradicting. See [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13098/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don’t understand your question.  BTW there may have been multiple close reasons and the system takes the one with the more votes (I think), and I may have voted to close because it was unclear.

From your question:

> How can this proof be generalized to a multiple-object system, considering the forces between those objects are conservative?

Why can’t you take $T$ to be the total kinetic energy and $V$ to be the total potential energy?  That and simply repeating the steps of your question will yield (basically) $f=ma$, albeit in component form and in a possible sub-efficient coordinate system.  That’s what textbooks and homework questions require you to do.

Moreover, your question is now linked to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78138/36194) and near-duplicate of it so it could also have collected close votes as a duplicate.

Comment: err... Why doing so won't work is explained in edit 1.

Comment: so the potential is a function $V(q_1,q_2)$.  So what else?  Just take the appropriate partials.  We must be talking at cross purposes here...