# Non-question: experimenting with custom close-reason banners in different contexts

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

I'm experimenting with editing close reasons, so here's a "question" that I can immediately close.

Here's how the custom close reason looks in the close-question dialog:

> [image: close-question dialog]

Here's how the close banner looks to a logged-out user:

> [image: logged-out banner]

Here's how the close banner looks to the author of the post:

> [image: author banner]

Here's how it looks to a non-author with the privilege to cast open and close questions. (Thanks, FakeMod.)

> [image: privileged-user banner]

Comment: FWIW, I have close/reopen votes priviledges, and [this is how it looks to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap852.jpg).

Comment: Thanks! I edited it in.

Comment: Is the goal to eventually propose how each of these will look for each closure reason on the main site?

Comment: Maybe this is a good time to mention that I have seen multiple members say that the message that *they* see when their question is closed tells them that they can edit the question *or post a new one*. Then, after they choose to post a new one,  we say “You’re not supposed to post a new one” and they say “WT-? You told me I could!”

Comment: @G.Smith If the new post is an obvious and sufficient improvement then it shouldn't be an issue. I guess people get confused though and think they can just copy and paste the same exact post.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Something like that. The goal for today was to understand which inputs ended up displayed where. I didn't understand that there are now four different message display contexts: we can show different messages to close voters, to logged-out viewers of closed posts, to post authors, and to potential reopen voters.

Comment: @G.Smith I have that impression, too, but I can never find that advice when I go to hunt for and remove it. If you (or anybody else) happens upon advisory text that makes folks think they should just copy-and-paste a bad question into a new post, please put a link on Meta and let's get rid of it.

Comment: @rob I agree with the point G. Smith raised. My memory says that I have at least encountered one question of this kind every month. As for evidence, most of the reposted (nearly copy-paste) questions have the originals deleted (either by community voting or voluntary deletion), so it is hard for me (don't have the 10k priviledge) to exactly determine such posts. Rummaging through some of my comments, I have found [one such instance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/571604/discrepancy-between-two-calculations-for-the-power-provided-by-pump#comment1288711_571604).

Comment: There have been other comments made by me as well, but I am too busy to find them and they might have been deleted along with the questions as well. Also, removing the *"ask a new question"* part will allow us a wee bit of more space for adding something more important to the close-banner text. IMO, it is worth taking up.