# A question (quoted below) was asked which I answered, and my answer was deleted. I would like to ask the logical reason for the deletion

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

The question:

> https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/657234 (now deleted and visible only to users with 10k+ rep; [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwFPD.jpg))

This seems to me to clearly be a question seeking a "Yes" or "No" answer. The question was preceded by reasoning clearly supporting the "Yes" answer, so I added to my answer, "Your reasoning is excellent." Accompanying the deletion of my answer were the following comments:

1. "An answer should contain arguments."
2. "This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post."

In response to these comments:

1. Why should a Yes-No question need an argument?
2. In what way is this comment related to the question and answer?

Comment: The second comment was auto-generated from the *low quality posts* review queue – the user reviewing apparently thought that your answer should have been a comment. The premade text doesn't always fit perfectly.

Comment: @Jonas My question to you regarding (2) is why is "Yes" not an answer to a Yes-No question?

Comment: @Giorgio? My question to you regarding (1) is is" WHY is your review a REASONABLE review? Why should an answer contain arguments, particularly when the question is a Yes-No question?

Comment: @Urb Thank you for your edits.

Answer (score 9):

The question linked, in its current form (v2), suffers from the issue pointed out by ACuriousMind in the second part of [this comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/657234/was-the-universes-relative-dark-energy-content-close-to-zero-right-after-the-be#comment1475019_657234). Essentially, seems like a check-my-understanding question. These types of questions are not very good, since they encourage answers that do not really add value to the site and will only be useful to the asker. Besides, our Q&A format, by design, needs answers which are more substantive than a simple yes or no. Read the answers to:

- [Are "check my understanding" questions permitted?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13109/149907)
- [Self Study Students: Confirmation Type Questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6669/149907)

and more generally

- [Should any check-my-work questions be made on topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/149907)

to get an idea of how the community feels about this topic.

Comment: Thank you much for the clarity. I think I now understand the specific relevant community criterion for acceptable questions and answers. I confess that I am disappointed since my personal point of view is different.

Answer (score 2):

Since the reference to the username was cut (@Giorgio instead of @GiorgioP), I did not receive notice of this post.

I wrote in a comment *An answer should contain arguments* and I maintain this is my point of view.

The reason I can give is pretty simple. This site is an open space, and questions and answers should not be considered private conversations between the asker and who answers. Therefore, even if everything would be obvious for them, I feel that answers should contain some rational argument supporting an affirmative or negative yes/no understandable by everybody else. Otherwise, it would be a kind of authority principle. It could work in the case of a university lecture. It cannot work here. Remember that independently of what we are in real life, here we are just nicknames.