# Request to reopen an old question

Tags: support, reopen

I am following the advice [given in community wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question#:%7E:text=Voting%20to%20reopen,question%2C%20not%20only%20their%20own.) and making a request to the Physic.SE community to reopen [this question.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/402007/doubt-on-an-answer-to-a-mechanics-problem)

The reason I believe the question should be reopened is because it is not a homework question but more of a conceptual question. This question falls in the type 4 category as per [ACuriousMind's post here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic), which most members accept are worthy of being kept open. The OP had provided proper justification for both the type of derivation and is not a solve-my-problem type of question.

As such I believe that the question should be reopened.

P.S: I have also edited the question and improved the LaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly I don’t think the item 4) you suggest applies.
This item states that check-my-work question could be allowed when they are of the type

*It seems as if step X is wrong? But it should be right because of Y, so why is this not the case?*

Here, we have two competing derivations.  Nowhere in either exposition does the OP identify a step X which is wrong, and justify it should be right because of Y. Rather OP is plainly asking for other users to decide which of the two methods is right.

I was one of the original closers, and I don’t remember why I voted to close.  Looking at it now the question suffers from other problems.  For starters, the variable $x$ of method 1 is defined as the extension of the spring whereas in method 2 the variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ are defined from the center of mass.

The extension of the spring should be (if I understand well) $x_1-x_2$, not $x_1+x_2$.  This way, if both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are displaced by the same amount, the spring is not stretched or compressed.  Because so little details are provided, it is impossible to verify one way or the other.

I would vote to close again as check-my-work or as unclear.

Clarifications could include the actual FBD illustrating the forces, a coordinate system from which the definition of $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x$ can easily be grasped.  This way, the OP could identify steps where the parallel development of the two solutions differ in an essential way, and could then proceed to identify a principle which seems to apply in one case but not another - at least bring it closer to the spirit of the format you quote.