# When does a closed question become open?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, specific-question, reopen

I have posted a question, *[Fidelity between initial state and final state](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/658628/)*. But due to inadequate details, it got closed. Now I have added details as much as possible. When will my question open again?

Answer (score 6):

The first edit after closure automatically enqueues the question [for reopen review](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/354379).

When the reopen review finishes depends on how many users currently use the review queues, how full the queues are, and how many feel qualified to judge your particular question, so it is difficult to predict exact time-frames. Our site does not generally work in real-time, but asynchronously.

Comment: Can I write the same question again and post it?

Comment: @AEIOU Please do not repost questions - in particular, while the current form no longer lacks details, it very likely falls under our policy against [check-my-work](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) and homework-like question and would just be closed again.