# Question closed despite being popular

Tags: discussion

I have asked four questions in recent days and all of them are being closed for the same *annoying reason*. [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/737711/square-wheels-on-bumpy-road-setup), despite garnering popular attention, was closed due to the same reason:

> Homework-like questions and check-my-work questions are considered
> off-topic here, particularly when asking about specific computations
> instead of underlying physics concepts

Well, in all questions I tried to present the question and even showed my active attempt to solve them. I also asked *if* I am lacking any crucial concept which I probably am, which is why I asked it here.

However, to no avail; they are all being closed down. They say homework-like questions are off-topic. Then why even bother adding a tag for the same, if they are bound to be closed anyway? I have seen questions that end in a few lines asking bluntly about some idea, and they are hardly closed down.

I would like to at least reopen the latest question which I actively researched and added all parts of it to the question.

Comment: Have you read the meta post on [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) linked in the closing notice? In what way do you think your question is on-topic by the criteria laid out in that post?

Comment: @ACuriousMind There really is a thin line between asking for conceptual difficulty and asking if my approach is wrong. Sure I have asked for conceptual difficulty here. Also I had shown my approach which in criterion with this site. So you are contradicting yourself.

Comment: Where do you see a contradiction here? Where did you get the idea from that showing your work is a *sufficient* criterion? The [other post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/715/50583) linked in the closing notice explicitly says *"It's not enough to just show your work and ask where you went wrong."*

Comment: @ACuriousMind I asked for a concpetual difficulty, I showed my motivation, work, and also tried to link it with real life by providing a link to video. What I rather see is that top questions on this site are just dumb questions like What is wormhole, pls explain, I read it somewhere, while deep conceptual questions like mine are disregarded as homework.

Comment: I am confused by this response. You claimed that there was a contradiction somewhere in our policies (or in what I have written). I asked you where that contradiction is, and your response is to generically call other people's questions "dumb" instead of actually pointing out a contradiction.

Comment: @ACuriousMind  By dumb I meant literally asking for something like please tell why kinetic energy is 1/2mv² or something like that, which has around 200 votes. Like the question didn't even showed active participation from user, showed his motivation, provided his own thinking which you guys always seek for. Just bluntly asked questions, and there are countless examples of it. I would suggest dropping this homework tag altogether, A physics question/setup or experiment must be looked as a puzzle/challenge to solve whether it's assignment question or whatever.

Answer (score 7):

With all due respect, it is difficult to read your OP and *not* think it is an assignment question.  In particular, statements like

> Please help me. Is my approach wrong? suggest some other way if you can. Thank you

is basically begging for others to do the work for you.

There is a conceptual core to your question but have not done a good job of highlighting it.

For instance, $p_1$ and $p_2$ are not properly defined in your figure so it is *conceptually* difficult to understand what $I_{p_1}\omega_1=I_{p_2}\omega_2$ really mean.

Your values of $I_{p_1}$ and $I_{p_2}$ are not clear, especially as the moment of inertia is given as $ma^2/6$.  Are you invoking the [parallel-axis theorem](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/parax.html)? For completeness,  $v_{req}$ is also not defined.

There is also here the question of someone supplying (in the video at least) an external force by pedalling, so it's not clear why angular momentum should be conserved although the video seems to illustrate something a little different from the question you're asking.

On balance, I have to say this looks like homework question where a student is stuck and is asking (in your case explicitly) for help, which is reason enough to close.  It can be rephrased as a conceptual question if you clarify some of the terminology.  In particular, given you have the answer, I would personally expect an energy argument (based on the rotational kinetic energy) would appear somewhere, but this is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Yes I am using parralel axis theorem, and the points depicted are basically points of contacts at two positions of square 1st being original and second being during lowest position. I thought that it is such a basic thing which can be easily understood by audience.

Comment: you should clarify the question accordingly.