# May I know how can I improve my question?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

[Gravitation and Electrostatics - A mathematical analogy or much more?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/791935/)

I posted this question, and though really good answers have been posted, it has been closed off.

I am a new member here, and would like to know your expectations on this.

Please let me know how I can improve my question.

Comment: Did you look here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 4):

> It would be nice if anyone could validate these observations. Further points showering more clarity of the same are also highly welcome.

is too open-ended, and the first part pretty much off-topic as a [check-my-work question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583). Around here, we expect questions to be *specific* so that it's easy to judge whether answers are answering the question or not. Just inviting users to add "further points" is the opposite of a specific question, in particular because it remains unclear what connection between electrostatics and gravitation *exactly* you think you have found.

For examples of more specific questions about the analogy between gravitational physics and electromagnetism, see e.g. [Geometric interpretation of electromagnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76354/50583) or [Has a metric formulation of electromagnetism ever been attempted?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/123862/50583).